# React-Table returning remaining items after filtering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-table

For this example of React-Table that uses multi-select, any ideas on how to not use a select box and just be able to click the row... and then do the REVERSE of what this example does...

That the clicked row is filtered out and saved in state, but then the remainder of the table is re-rendered?   Perhaps actually the state is all the data and we remove?   But this would be very very bad if we have millions of records.

https://codesandbox.io/s/3x51yzollq

Answer (score 0):

To be able to click the row and select it you can use `getTrProps`

```
data={this.state.data}
getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
  if (rowInfo && rowInfo.original) {
    return {
      onClick: () => {
        // handle select
        this.handleSingleCheckboxChange(rowInfo.index);
      }
    };
  } else {
      return {};
  }
}}
```

And in the function that handle select, you can filter out and rerender

```
handleSingleCheckboxChange = index => {
  //filter and setState to change data
  let newData = this.state.data;
  newData = newData .filter(value => value !== newData[index]);
  this.setState({ data: newData });
};
```